# doctrine dbal querybuilder as prepared statement

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to create a Doctrine DBAL querybuilder object and setting a parameter in it.
(using a postgres db, dbal 2.3.4, doctrine

```
$connection = $this->_em->getConnection();
$qb = $connection->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('tbl_user_contract.pkid AS pkid');
$qb->from('tbl_user_contract', 'tbl_user_contract');
$qb->join('tbl_user_contract', 'tbl_user', 'tbl_user', 'tbl_user_contract.fk_user = tbl_user.pkid');
$qb->where('tbl_user.pkid = :userid');
$qb->setParameter(':userid', 10);
```

When I try to get the results of this querybuilder object I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[08P01]: <<Unknown error>>: 7 ERROR: bind message supplies 0 parameters, 
but prepared statement "pdo_stmt_00000002" requires 1
```

When I check the postgres logs, I see the query passing by and I notice that it expects a parameter, but I won't get a parameter passed in.

I tried to set the id in the where expression itself (without using prepared statements), that worked. But I really want to get this working with prepared statements.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You use a `?` wildcard for the param, but then try to set it by name. Usually you have to use *either* named parameters or ordinal position parameters, not mix the two. Maybe you need to try something like 
`$qb->setParameter(1, 10);` ? (it might count from zero or from one). I don't use Doctrine or PHP so this is untested.

Comment: Excuse me, did something wrong when copy-pasting parts of code to stackoverflow. Changed it to both named parameters, but the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 5):

I think you just need to remove colon from `setparameter` command

```
$qb->setParameter('userid', 10);
```

At least it works in Doctrine help https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.9/reference/query-builder.html

Comment: That doesn't seem to do the trick. Same error when I'm not using the colon.

Answer (score 1):

The setParameter part of your querybuillder function is wrong.  You do not need the :, you can put it all on one line like this, and only include one talbe in your FROM statement.  You may have a problem in your JOIN or FROM statement if there is another table named tbl_user and need to check your entity definitions to make sure the annotations are correct.

```
$connection = $this->_em->getConnection();
$qb = $connection->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('tbl_user_contract.pkid AS pkid')
  ->from('tbl_user_contract')
  ->join('tbl_user_contract', 'tbl_user', 'tbl_user', 'tbl_user_contract.fk_user =   tbl_user.pkid')
  ->where('tbl_user.pkid = :userid')
  ->setParameter('userid', 10);
```

Refer to the docs here http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#binding-parameters-to-your-query.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem with DBAL 2.5.13.

I'm writing a tool that uses Symfony components and DBAL, therefore there is no `entityManager` object but to maintain similar structure due team previous knowledge with Symfony, I made a repository class with a method like:

```
public function getAtendimentoRealFromOffline($foo3, $foo4)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder()
                    ->select("foo1, foo2")
                    ->from("bar_table")
                    ->andWhere("foo3 = :foo3")
                    ->andWhere("foo4 = :foo4")
                    ->setParameter(":foo3", $foo3)
                    ->setParameter(":foo4", $foo4);
}
```

---

Now if you run like:

```
$this->connection->fetchAll($query);
```

It will indeed show you the error, because you're using the fetchAll from connection with no relation at all with the statement you just created with `QueryBuilder`. One solution would be use the second parameter to send an array of parameters:

```
$this->connection->fetchAll($query, ["foo3" => "bar3", "foo4" => "bar4"]);
```

and you can remove the `setParameters` from the query builder:

```
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder()
                    ->select("foo1, foo2")
                    ->from("bar_table")
                    ->andWhere("foo3 = :foo3")
                    ->andWhere("foo4 = :foo4")
```

---

What can be unseen by the documentation is that the `QueryBuilder` actually has an execute method, which will then indeed run with the parameters, therefore you can just:

```
$query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states you can do the following:

```
$queryBuilder
    ->select('id', 'name')
    ->from('users')
    ->where('email = ' .  $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($userInputEmail))
;
```

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.9/reference/query-builder.html#binding-parameters-to-placeholders

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$qb->where('tbl_user.pkid = :userid');
$qb->setParameter(':userid', 10);
```

then

```
 $params = $qb->getParameters();
 $stmt = $connection->prepare($qb->getSQL());
 foreach ($params as $key=>$value){
    $stmt->bindParam($key,$value);
 }

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAllAssociative();
```